# ArchLinux DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: dns, home-networking, arch-linux

I am a newbie and currently facing this problem.

I use systemd tools to configure network.

`systemd-networkd.service` and `systemd-resolved.service` are up running.

Note: I have to use this static IP.

`/etc/systemd/network/wired.network` looks as following:

```
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
Address=192.168.70.6
Gateway=192.168.70.101
DNS=192.168.70.101
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

The first DNS is necessary to resolve the fritz.box URL.

So, for example, I tried to access `docs.kde.org` with Chromium.
The result was a Chromium Error Page showing `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.
I tried several DNS Configurations, like

```
 DNS=192.168.70.101
```

or

```
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

or

```
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4
```

or even

```
DNS=192.168.70.6 
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4
```

None of them worked, it still shows the error. The `systemd-networkd.service` was restarted after every edit via `systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service`. Of course I reloaded the page via `F5`.
Accessing the page works fine when doing it with the Windows 10 installed in dual boot.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Fix what exactly?  What are you trying to do when that error shows up?